# Is there any relationship between a compact set and a connected set?

Tags: general-topology

Is there any relationship between a compact set and a connected set?

or If A is compact set does that tell you anything about whether its connected set or not?

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 7):

No. If $\Bbb R$ has its usual topology, the set $[0,1]$ is compact and connected; the set $[0,1]\cup[2,3]$ is compact but not connected; the set $\Bbb R$ is connected but not compact; and the set $\Bbb Z$ is neither compact nor connected.